# Timing two parallel lines on FPGA [Beginner]

Tags: fpga, timing

So let's suppose I want to do certain action based on certain signal.
I have signal "nx"; if it's 1, I want to "NOT" an X input(16bit) and if it isn't, I want the X unchanged.

My idea was to do both and fanout it into MUX and decide which output to use based on the "nx" bit. But I'm not so sure if it would work in real hardware (or even FPGA for that matter), because the lane that doesn't change anything is gonna be carried out faster than the one with "NOT" gates in it.

[image: Two lanes into mux, 1 NOT 1 w/o NOT]

Is my understanding correct ? And if so, is it problem even on FPGA (do those operations really "eat" clock cycles) ? And if so, how would you go about it to solve this simple problem ?

Comment: Things on an FPGA don't "eat clock cycles" in the way you're thinking. Everything you put into a process will all take take one clock cycle. If the synthesizer cannot route that process and meet your clock constraints, it will tell you and you will either have to modify the design, or run with a slower clock. This "manualness" lets you time everything that happens in an FPGA down to the clock cycle, unlike a processor where you don't have full control of how many clock cycles something might take.

Comment: So  one path can be faster than the other. Every combinatorial circuit has different length paths. But as long as you give it enough time to propagate you will have the correct result. This is why we have a notion of a "critical path". Combinatorial circuits do not have clocks.

Comment: "Combinatorial circuits do not have clocks", that sums it all nicely. Thanks you both so much for the awesome answers!!! I'll take a look at the warnings, if any emerge then

Answer (score 1):

> Is my understanding correct ?

Even aside from your misunderstanding of "clock cycles", which has been addressed in comments, your intuition about propagation time is actually incorrect here.

The function you're describing would be implemented as a single 2-LUT for each bit of X (with the function `Xout[i] = X[i] ^ NX`), not as two separate combinational paths. The propagation time of the LUT is independent of the logic which it was synthesized from.

In practice, this 2-LUT would probably be absorbed into LUTs used for other logic surrounding this function.

Comment: Oh.. I never thought of using XOR for this. Genius! Is there any rule (apart from basic boolean algebra or practice) on figuring these solutions out ? I'm still learning the ropes

Comment: Agreed, most logic turns into LUTs for an FPGA, but I don't think you can be certain that all delay paths will have exactly the same timing through a LUT/multiplexer. The select inputs will need to be inverted, then their true and complement values will select a mux input. The inverter for the select lines will introduce some skew in the path delays.